Aspire sample app - hidden css Web.styles.css?
I have created the Aspire sample app in Visual Studio 2022.
in App.razor you can see it references the stylesheet styles.css under the Web project:

I had no problem finding app.css, but I can't seem to find styles.css, is it a hidden file or something only present at runtime?? I can actually find the file in the debug folder and nowhere else.
Here is a screenshot of the files and folders in Solution Explorer:

You can see other default CSS files there, but no styles.css. I also tried doing a code search in Visual Studio, it finds styles.css in App.razor but nowhere else. I would like to be able to access the file and make modifications. Does anyone know where/how to locate it?
Also I tried commenting out the line in App.razor and I can see the styling on the pages is different, so I know it's being applied.

The file AspireSampleApp.Web.styles.css is a CSS bundle created from the CSS found under each of your Razor components. In your solution explorer you can find these under Components/Layout/ in your web app (AspireSampleApp.Web).
For more information see:

ASP.NET Core Blazor CSS isolation


I have expanded the folder Components/Layout, but there is only MainLayout.razor.css and NavMenu.razor.css there.

@SendETHToThisAddress  Yes, but those CSS files get bundled together automatically at runtime and then they're accessible via that "generated"<stylesheet>  tag. I do recommend reading the article I linked to which explains what is happening here. There's no magic going on and it isn't specific to Aspire. Bundling like this has been around a long time in the .NET eco-system.

Thanks Kev, I understand what you mean now, the file generated with the build and only found in the bin folder.
